# Bar plot with plotly grouped and stacked as is

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

My input:

```
    df=(pd.DataFrame({'label_color':['white','white','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','white','white'],
                  'label_quality':['white','white','red','green','green','red','white','white'],
'label':['foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo','foo']}))
```

Let me explain what I want: "One column" will be `label color` and "Second column" will be `label_quality`, where `x.axis` is `df.index` and correlated position columns with order of index. Also `y.axis` is just name of label. And `colors` is values from df columns["label_colors ","label_quality"]

Here solution that provide `@r_beginners`:

```
df['color_value'] = 1
df['quality_value'] = 1

fig = px.bar(df, y=['color_value','quality_value'],
             x=[1]*len(df),
             orientation='h',
             barmode='group',
             template='plotly_white')

fig.data[0]['marker']['color'] = df['label_color'].tolist()
fig.data[1]['marker']['color'] = df['label_quality'].tolist()
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)')
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='foo', xaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

But ion real data its looks some strange:

[image]

seems like that column borders overlapped:

[image]

I find solution: `fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='rgb(255,255,255)', marker_line_width=0 )`

So:

[image]

Hope it will be helpful anyone who want visualization data

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. It's a common phenomenon when a simplified solution to a problem is applied to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you presented does not match the content of the x-axis of the graph, but in order to achieve what you want, you need to add values for each of them, because you cannot draw a graph with just the color names. In addition, after completing the horizontal bar graph, I have updated the list of columns with the desired colors. The color of the border is changed to determine whether it is blank or white with respect to color. Depending on the purpose of the graph, a Gantt chart may be preferable to a timeline.

```
df['color_value'] = 1
df['quality_value'] = 1

fig = px.bar(df, y=['color_value','quality_value'],
             x=[1]*len(df),
             orientation='h',
             barmode='group',
             template='plotly_white')

fig.data[0]['marker']['color'] = df['label_color'].tolist()
fig.data[1]['marker']['color'] = df['label_quality'].tolist()
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)')
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='foo', xaxis_title='')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, you are right I guess I need assignee to 'color_value' and 'quality_value' at a index in order they are on scale of index or not? One is fine, because y-scale just a label

Comment: To remove the tick marks on the y-axis, add the following code. `fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[''])`

Comment: Hi, I update plot with real data and its looks some strange

Comment: What version of the software are you currently using? I am using the latest version at 5.5.0.

Comment: same version 5.5.0. I think problem is not version, but in real data there ~2100 "columns", so i try hide gap with `fig.update_layout(showlegend=False, yaxis_title='Actions.irrigations', xaxis_title='', bargap=0.0,bargroupgap=0.0, barmode='group')`